# Automatic Numbering with ng-repeat

Tags: angular

However when there is a pagination in the next page, the count starts from 1 again. How to preserve the number across the paginations?

Currently I am using only the following

```
<td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
```

Comment: Please improve your question. Add the code that demonstrates what you have tried and where you failed. Did you try a search?

Comment: There is no `ng-repeat` in Angular2 and `*ngFor` doesn't support customizing the index.

Comment: How do we achieve an automatic numbering of a column then?

Comment: You can use `page * pageSize + $index`